# How to put live stream video inside the container using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and i read some stuffed about it, i have a medium knowledge about it, my question is , How do i put live video from the api ?

```
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

.....
final videocolumn = Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
    width: globals.screenWidth * 0.96,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(20),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey,width: 1.0,),
        ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
          Container(
            height: globals.screenHeight * 0.25,
             // get the live video from the api
          ),
       ]
    ),
);
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.2
  flutter_section_table_view: ^1.0.3
  page_transition: ^1.1.7+6
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_webrtc: ^0.5.8
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Please give an example using my code

just like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this : https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc

Comment: HI @Shubhamhackz, I've already saw that in github but i cant follow since the code is so advance for me. i just want that simple code that i can follow

Comment: From where are you getting the video ? Your own server or services like agora ?

Comment: @Shubhamhackz soon i will make own server, but for now, i just want services like agora or mux or anything that easy to follow and understand

Comment: This could be useful : https://medium.com/flutter-community/live-streaming-with-mux-stream-and-flutter-2c03d581b1b

Comment: @Shubhamhackz i've already saw this one, but i dont know how to put the paste that code in my project

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) plugin

```
    import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
    'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');

await videoPlayerController.initialize();

final chewieController = ChewieController(
  videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
  autoPlay: true,
  looping: true,
);

final playerWidget = Chewie(
  controller: chewieController,
);
```

dont forget to dispose the controller widget

```
    @override
void dispose() {
  videoPlayerController.dispose();
  chewieController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: is chewie plugin is advisable for getting the live streaming through api?

Comment: if you talking about live stream videos, i think the best plugin for that is "best player", but chewie is good for playing videos from network

Answer (score 1):

/* To create and initialize the VideoPlayerController do the following:

1. Create a StatefulWidget with a companion State class
2. Add a variable to the State class to store the VideoPlayerController
3. Add a variable to the State class to store the Future returned from
4. VideoPlayerController.initialize Create and initialize the controller in the initState method
5. Dispose of the controller in the dispose method  */

   ```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

    void main() => runApp(VideoPlayerApp());

    class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Video Player Demo',
          home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
        );
      }
    }

    class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      VideoPlayerScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
    }

    class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
      VideoPlayerController _controller;
      Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

      @override
      void initState() {
        // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
        // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
        // or the internet.
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
          'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4',
        );

        // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
        _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

        // Use the controller to loop the video.
        _controller.setLooping(true);

        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
        _controller.dispose();

        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Butterfly Video'),
          ),
          // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
          // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                );
              } else {
                // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                // loading spinner.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
   ```

   /*
   Play and pause the video
   By default, the video starts in a paused state. To begin playback, call the play() method provided by the VideoPlayerController. To pause playback, call the pause() method.
   For this example, add a FloatingActionButton to your app that displays a play or pause icon depending on the situation. When the user taps the button, play the video if it’s currently paused, or pause the video if it’s playing.
   */

   ```
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
              // correct icon is shown.
              setState(() {
                // If the video is playing, pause it.
                if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                  _controller.pause();
                } else {
                  // If the video is paused, play it.
                  _controller.play();
                }
              });
            },
            // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
            child: Icon(
              _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
            ),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video) the complete code and example for playing videos using an API. I think this should help you.

Comment: How about when app is open, the live video is automatic playing?

Comment: You will need to test it. However, I think it will work.